# Extract text from json field

Tags: mysql

My query looks like:

```
select
    id,
    json_extract(flow_settings, '$.email_settings_id') AS email_settings_id
from smsbump.flows
where flows.flow_trigger in ('Synergy/TierExpiryReminder',
        'integrations/swell_tier_earned',
        'integrations/swell_birthday',
        'integrations/swell_points_reminder',
        'integrations/swell_redemption_reminder',
        'integrations/cdp_optin_status_changed',
        'integrations/cdp_redemption_created') and flows.channel in ('email', 'all');
```

This how my json looks like:

```
{
   "platform":"shopify",
   "flow_type":"predefined",
   "cached":false,
   "flow":{
      "trigger":"integrations\/swell_redemption_reminder",
      "triggerOptions":[
         
      ],
      "steps":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "positive":2,
            "negative":false,
            "type":"action",
            "settings":{
               "notify":"customer",
               "ab_testing":{
                  "enabled":false,
                  "message_count":2,
                  "threshold_type":"orders",
                  "threshold_value":5,
                  "messages":[
                     
                  ]
               },
               "message":"{SiteName}: Hey {FirstName}, we haven't seen you in a while! Did you know you have {YotpoPointsBalance} points as part of our rewards program? That's enough for a discount!\nEvery 100 point =$10\n\nShop and redeem now! {SiteUrl}\n\nReply {StopToOpt}",
               "stop_to_opt_out_text":"STOP to opt out",
               "discount_code_settings":false,
               "recommended_product":[
                  
               ],
               "type":"sms",
               "addingMedia":false,
               "mediaPath":"",
               "mediaFile":[
                  
               ],
               "contact_card":false,
               "image":"",
               "contact_card_data":{
                  "name":"",
                  "logo":"",
                  "path":"",
                  "message":"{SiteName}: Save our number to your contact list and never miss a special deal from us. Be the first to know about new product launches and more."
               },
               "event":"integrations\/swell_redemption_reminder",
               "active":true
            }
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "positive":false,
            "negative":false,
            "type":"action",
            "settings":{
               "discount_code_settings":false,
               "type":"email",
               "personalized_recommended_product":false,
               "active":true,
               "email_settings_id":3023222
            }
         }
      ],
      "name":"Loyalty Redemption Reminder (SMS and Email)",
      "status":1,
      "id":625727,
      "created_user_id":56416521,
      "select_values_to_request":[
         
      ]
   }
}
```

So the problem is that `email_settings_id` is null for all record after executing my query.

I also tried to structure the path in the query like `$.flow.steps.email_settings_id` but again returns null.

**EDIT**
What I see now is that the field is actually `mediumtext` and not `json`. Is there a way to convert it during the query execution? Don't have the rights to alter that table.

Comment: the json is invalud and your path needs all the tags before the email_id but first fix the json

Comment: @nbk it is pretty much ok. I am pasting it http://json.parser.online.fr/ and no errors found.

Answer (score -1):

You can't access to `email_settings_id` because it is not in the top level, it is in the array flow_settings->flow.steps

You need to convert this JSON array into rows then retrieve `email_settings_id` using `json_extract()` or the operator `->` :

```
SELECT id, element->'$.settings.email_settings_id'
FROM flows
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
         flow_settings->"$.flow.steps",
         "$[*]"
         COLUMNS(
           element JSON PATH "$"
         )
       ) data;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/q0hUoZUu)

Comment: It actually again returns null.

Comment: In the fiddle is working fine ! Can you check your query without the where clause ?